# Proftpd with mariadb (mysql) backend unable to upload

Tags: permissions, proftpd

I have proftpd running with a mariadb (mysql) backend.

I have created a user `midas` in the ftp database.

At the moment of first login, proftpd (running as user `proftpd` and group `proftpd`) creates a home directory for this user located at `/var/ftp/`.

This works fine, I see the directory being created:

```
[root@vps ftp]# ls -la
total 24
drwxr-xr-x.  5 proftpd proftpd 4096 10 jul 19:19 .
drwxr-xr-x. 22 root    root    4096 10 jul 12:56 ..
drwxrwxr-x.  2 proftpd proftpd 4096 10 jul 19:34 midas
```

On the client side, issueing the `put` commando returns a `550: Permission denied`

```
ftp> put ~/website.zip remotewebsite.zip
local: /home/midas/website.zip remote: remotewebsite.zip
200 PORT command successful
550 remotewebsite.zip: Permission denied
```

To verify that I am in the correct directory, and that proftpd DOES have write access to this folder, I created an empty file `somefile`.:

`[proftpd@vps midas]$ touch somefile`
--> returns no errors and shows up for my user `midas` clientside.

```
ftp> ls
200 PORT command successful
150 Opening ASCII mode data connection for file list
-rw-rw-r--   1 1001     1001            0 Jul 10 17:48 somefile
226 Transfer complete
```

I am sure I'm missing some very basic understanding here, but I must confess this is the first time I'm working with virtual users.
Any pointers towards a solution would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dot at the end of the permissions set, makes me think you have a SELinux security context enabled :

```
drwxrwxr-x.  2 proftpd proftpd 4096 10 jul 19:34 midas
          ^--dot
```

Either disable SELinux or make it permissive within file `/etc/selinux/config` (both not recommended), or better, set the security context :

```
setsebool -P allow_ftpd_full_access on
```

Comment: This is correct. I have changed the security context and this works.

Thank you.

Comment: Also, +1 for the info about the `.`
I learned something new today :)